# how can I send signal to computer

Tags: arduino, serial-communication, arduino-c++

greetings to each of you. I need your help. I am working on a project. I need that when a > is greater than 5, the arduino sends a signal to the computer and starts playing the video on the computer. my computer operation system is Windows11. I want play video on windows media player or anything. everytime my computer is open and video on media player ready to play. I don't know how to do it. first I connected the servo motor, the servo motor rotated 70 degrees and hit the computer's "space" key. now I want to develop it further. When it enters the "if" period, it will send a signal and start playing the video automatically.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is `a`? Where did it come from? What's the servo supposed to be doing? How is that related to `a`? Is the servo typing mechanically somewhere? What's an *"if period"*? Where does the video come from? Is the PC running Windows or Linux? Sorry, it's all rather unclear to me. Maybe you can click [edit] and clarify things. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to think so complicated. With Java, C# or Python, you can code scripts where you can read values and take actions over the serial port. For Arduino side use `Serial.begin(9600);` in the `setup()` and write your code in `loop` as:

```
while (a > 5 )
{
    Serial.println(1);
}
```

While your `a` greater than 5 we send `1` value to serial port. Now I will continue to explain over python.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5')
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = float(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        print(decoded_bytes)
    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        break
```

You do your test and write your code in `try` section.